# Thevenin equivalent of open ended transmission line Clarifications required

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, impedance-matching, characteristic-impedance, reflection

I am going through the below link for understanding about transmission line reflections.

The below figure is an equivalent circuit of an open-ended transmission line. For finding the
the voltage at V+ why the author used voltage division.

This is an open-ended transmission line so the voltage at V+ should be the open-circuit voltage Vg?

May I know where I went wrong?

https://incompliancemag.com/article/transmission-line-reflections-at-a-resistive-load/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ignore half of the wave which starts to propagate along the wires to the right as soon as the battery is connected. The ignored half is the current component of the wave.

In the linked article there's clearly stated that the input voltage isn't constant DC which has stayed as is from t=minus eternity, the system is switched ON at t=0, so a wave starts to propagate.

The general solution of Telegrapher's Equations (see NOTE1) shows that the wave on the line contains simultaneously voltage and current components.

The current is not independent. In a single wave at every point of line at every moment there's current component i=u/Z where u is the voltage component of the wave. Z is the characteristic impedance of the line. The current is needed to charge and discharge the capacitor elements in the ladder network model of the transmission line.

At the beginning there's only one wave at the left end of the line - the reflection has not occurred nor generated the backwards wave. Thus the current component of to the right propagating wave is the only current, no need to sum together the current component of the reflected wave. Also there's no need to add anything reflected to the voltage component of the wave. That situation changes after the reflection happens.

So, if we assume there's voltage =Uo between the wires at the left end of the line at t=0, there's also at the same time at the same place current Io=Uo/Z. The +voltage is in the upper wire of the line, the current flows to the right in the upper wire and to the left in the lower wire when we talk about the left end of the line at t=0.

The general solution law of Telegrapher's Equations is not the only thing to be noticed. Also Ohm's law should be true for the resistor Rg and Kirchoff's laws must be respected. Note that at t=0 there's no need to be current in the right end of the line. The current at the left end is used to charge the line capacitance elements through the inductor elements.

At t=0 in the left end of the line we have due Kirchoff's law

Vg = Io * Rg + Uo.

If we substitute Io = Uo/Z we can solve Uo=(Z * Vg)/(Rg + Z) which is your problematic equation.

**NOTE1**: Read more of Telegrapher's Equations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations

The inventor of the equations is Oliver Heaviside. He really was a telegrapher (=the clerk who transmitted and receiver messages). As a mathematician and scientist he was only a hobbyist with no academic studies nor status, but a brilliant one.

BTW O.H. also had some luck (and we got it, too). No scientist or even no engineer would have been interested in telegraph clerks's papers. But O.H. happened to know some top notch academic persons via family relations and they saw the value of his writings.

Answer (score 2):

The transmission line appears initially to be a lumped element of its specified impedance.  Only after the signal travels at the speed of light to the open end, and the return signal travels back to z=0, does the transmission line at z=0 appear to be open.  Instantaneous response would violate relativity.

Comment: That's correct.  It looks like Zc until the reflected signal gets back to Z=0.